# When deleting the last node in linked-list, i am assigning temp to null, but it's still there and not deleted. Java

Tags: java, singly-linked-list

When deleting the last node in linked-list, i am assigning temp to null, but it's still there and not deleted. (Java)

```
public void deleteFromBack() {

        if (!isEmpty()) {
            Node temp = first;
            while (temp.next != null) {
                temp = temp.next;
            }
            temp=null;

        }
    }
```

```
Output:
5
9
6
7
After deleting last node: 
5
9
6
7
```

Comment: We can't give you any sort of answer without seeing the code for your entire list implementation.  Deleting a node is more complicated than this, because you have to do some splicing to remove it (most of the time).

Comment: sho your entire code then we can undestand

Comment: Well what is not empty in this line`if (!isEmpty()) {`? Please share complete code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not deleting the node in the snippet you wrote in the OP. You are just assigning `null` to temp.

```
    if (!isEmpty()) {
        Node temp = first;
        Node previousNode = null;
        while (temp.next != null) {
            previousNode = temp;
            temp = temp.next;
        }
        previousNode.next = null;
    }
```

To delete the node off the list, you need to make value of the node which holds the reference to the last node null.

Comment: why not just assigning the node to null doesn't delete it ? may you explain more plz ?

Comment: because temp doesnt "contain" the node, it just stores the reference to it. In other words, temp knows the address where the node is stored. When you change the content of temp it will have no effect on the node itself.

Answer (score 0):

What you're setting to null is `temp`, which is a local variable; as soon as the block it's declared in is left, it's going out of scope so setting it to `null` has no effect.

What you want to do is setting the `next` element of that node to null, so the tail is cut off.

```
temp.next = null;
```

However, since you're looping until you find a node with `next` set to `null` already, you'll have to remember one before that. Also, you'll need a special case for the last element in the list.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is `temp` variable is just another reference variable which is pointing to last node of linked list along with second last node.

For example:-

```
SecondLastNode.next---\
                       \
                        ------>LastNodeOflinkedList  
                       /
temp------------------/
```

In your Scenario, you are only assigning `null` to `temp` while `SecondLastNode.next` is still pointing to last node.

Resolution:-

Assign `null` to `SecondLastNode.next`